# SOAP Connection WCF

Tags: wcf, soap

I am connecting to a 3rd party API. They have provided me with a WSDL file which i have added by using a web reference. Is it possible to connect via SOAP and send multiple messages across the same connection?

I have created the client from the proxy classes but there doesn't appear to be a Open() or a Close() method. Does the client connect and disconnect when a method is called?

```
SampleService client = new SampleService

client.SampleMethod();
```

Edit:

I have added a "Service Reference" from the WSDL file. The client is constructed from the "PortType" in the WSDL file. There inst a Close() or a Abort() method. The only method on SampleService.client is SampleMethod()

Comment: Please accept an answer, or if you answered the question yourself add and accept a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They have provided me with a WSDL file which i have added by using a web reference.

In such case you are not using WCF but ASP.NET WebServices client. In your case it is probably not a big difference but ASP.NET WebServices are mostly for backward compatibility when moving legacy code to new version of .NET framework. Today you should rather use Add Service Reference to use WCF as other also recommended.

> SOAP Connection WCF

There is nothing like SOAP connection. SOAP is application protocol tunneled through some transport protocol. In your case the transport protocol is HTTP.

> I have created the client from the proxy classes but there doesn't
>   appear to be a Open() or a Close() method. Does the client connect and
>   disconnect when a method is called?

You don't need to call `Open` or `Close`. This is all handled in low level layer of communication stack. By default all HTTP client applications use something called persistent connection. It means that when you access some host for the first time TCP connection is established between your client computer and server hosting target resource. Subsequent calls reuse the same connection. If the connection is not in use for some predefined time (both client and server can have different timeouts) the connection is closed and next time the client wants to call the server it will create a new connection (again you don't need to bother with this).

So calling the method on SOAP proxy in your application can automatically open connection if no one exists. You don't need to explicitly close the connection but you should dispose the proxy to release its resources. Connection itself can live after the proxy was disposed and can be reused by another proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You have helped me a lot on other posts! I am unsure what you mean by dispose the proxy but keep the connection open. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Long time ago when I played with this I found that disposing proxy actually doesn't close the connection because connection can be reused by other proxies - that is all handled internally. All opened connections will be closed once they time out (when not used for some time) or once you close the application. There is also limit to number of opened connections to single host.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a service reference (WCF) instead of using the outdated Web Reference.

Then follow the bellow pattern:

```
try
{
    SampleServiceClient client = new SampleServiceClient();
    client.SampleMethod();
    //... Make as many calls to as many methods as you like.
    client.SampleMethod();
    client.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //client is unusable once an exception occurs.
    ...
    client.Abort();
    throw;
}
```

Comment: If I add a "Service Reference" the only methods available are the methods exposed by the 3rd party service. There inst a Close or a Abort method. The client is constructed from the "PortType" in the WSDL file?

Comment: Actually its because i was creating the client from the interface instead of the class. ISampleServiceClient client = new SampleServiceClient(); Why are the methods not on the interface?

Comment: @ministrymason - ISampleServiceClient is a custom interface defined by your third party friends, not by Mircosoft or WCF.  It would be silly for the host server to have to implement Open() and Close(), as they are only useful to the client.

Comment: ye makes sense,. Thanks for the responses and clearing things up. I have it working now using WCF

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Add Service Reference rather than Add Web Reference. And once added you can invoke the service as shown:

```
using(SampleServiceClient client = new SampleServiceClient())
{
    var response = client.SampleMethod();
}
```

Hope that helps.